# JSON Parsing Hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js for node.js development. I need help getting a specific set of data from a json file, but I can't seem to figure out how to parse it to return what I need.

JSON Sample

```
    {
      "books": [{
        "book1": {
          "chapters": [{
            "ch1" : {   
              "v1": "v1",
              "v2": "v2"
            },
            "ch2" : {   
              "v1": "v1",
              "v2": "v2"
            }
          }]
        },
        "book2": {
          "chapters": [{
            "ch1" : {   
              "1": "v1",
              "2": "v2"
            },
            "ch2" : {   
              "1": "x1",
              "2": "x2"
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
```

And here's my underscore.js code

```
    _.each(parse.books[0], function (v, b) {
        return b; 
      });
```

Which returns:
book1
book2

Now, my next step is where I'm having trouble. I need to get all of the chapters for each book within that same .each function. Here's what I want to do:

```
    _.each(parse.books[0], function (v, b) {
          return b;
    //Get Chapters
        _.each(bible.books[0].b.chapters[0], function (v, c) {
          return c; 
        });
      });
```

When I use "b" in the second .each, "b" does not call each book name in the loop as I would expect it to. I don't want to have to write out each book name individually. I need it in the loop. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bible.books[0][b].chapters[0]` instead of `bible.books[0].b.chapters[0]`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It's funny that I tried it as you showed but with a period between like this: [0].[b]. It's funny how 1 period can completely throw everything off!